# Text becomes undefined when going through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Now, I'm new to web programming, javascript in particular. I'm trying to write a script that will update the image on a webpage and its text when the user clicks the image. Here's the code:

```
//Images array
imgs = Array("test1.jpg", "test2.jpg", "test3.jpg");

//Names array
names = Array("Test1", "Test2", "Test3");

//Holds how many times our page has been clicked
var click = 0;

//Another click var
var click2 = 0;

//change function 
function change()
{

//Get the ID of 'nam', and start incrementing the elements in our array
document.getElementById("nam").innerHTML = names[++click2];

//Get an element with the ID 'first', and start incrementing the elements in  our      array
document.getElementById("first").src = imgs[++click];

//If the user clicks to the end of the gallery
if(click==2)
{
    click = -1;
}

if(click2==2)
{
    click = -1;
}

}
```

Probably not the best way to do this, but this code will work at first. However, when I click the third image to go back to the first, the pictures work fine, but the text becomes 'undefined'. I've searched around, but I can't seem to find anything really 'wrong' with this code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Create an array with `[..]`. Not with `Array(..)`. It should be `new Array(..)` in your example actually.

Comment: Seeing that you're new to Js: please note that it's considered bad practice to use the `Array` and `Object` constructors explicitly. It's even worse when you omit the `new` keyword. So either use the (_bad_) `new Array();` or the generally used (and accepted as better alternative) `var myArray = []; var myObject = {};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in var name:

```
//If the user clicks to the end of the gallery
if(click==2)
{
    click = -1;
}

if(click2==2)
{
    click = -1;
}
```

should be

```
//If the user clicks to the end of the gallery
if(click==2)
{
    click = -1;
}

if(click2==2)
{
    click2 = -1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Something as stupid as a typo caused me twenty minutes of grief.

Answer (score 1):

you are increment the click and click2 then applying it. you should intialize click 
 and click2 with -1; since click initialized by 0, names[++click2] will return second item not first.

```
var click = -1;

//Another click var
var click2 = -1;
```

also

```
if(click2==2)
{
    click = -1;
}
```

should be

```
if(click2==2)
{
    click2 = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure to call available indexes of your `names` and `imgs`. After the third one, you'll call number `4` and this isn't defined.

You could do it this way:

`document.getElementById("nam").innerHTML = names[(++click2)%names.length];`

`document.getElementById("first").src = imgs[(++click)%imgs.length];`

This will keep the numbers between 0 and 2.

Things that happens: The operator `%` in `a % b` returns you the rest when dividing `a` by `b`. For example is `5 % 2 == 1`.

Comment: Good solution. But explain what the modulus does.

Answer (score 1):

your last if statement doesn't assign click2 to -1. change it to be click2 = -1